# Folder pushes to multiple github repos

Tags: git

If I have the files

```
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php
file4.php
```

Can I assign files *file1.php* and *file2.php* to one repo then all the rest to another repo? I'm curious since doing so can allow me to create repos for specific files of my site where each represents a different set of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can add and remove other remotes at any time but the git repository itself only has 1 location.
This one location is where git stores what has been added and removed and it is not based or linked to what remotes exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with symlinking?

```
ln -s /path/to/repo1/file1.php /path/to/file1.php
ln -s /path/to/repo1/file2.php /path/to/file2.php
ln -s /path/to/repo2/file3.php /path/to/file3.php
ln -s /path/to/repo2/file4.php /path/to/file4.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to play with this: https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree

Comment: I *think* that with some fiddling you'd be able to do what you want with that. But this seems to me as going against the "system", so maybe you should try to rethink what you're doing first.

Comment: I thought so too. Does this mean that using multiple forks in a single project is discouraged? :-(

Comment: I'd say that is not a job for Git, but rather a job for your system/framework packager.